# Worst & Best Player based on PPG

Tags: c

I'm trying to output the best and worst players based on their points-per-game.

My issue is with calculating worstPlayer. I don't know how to keep track of bestPPG relative to my other if-statement, or else I feel that I have the right idea. I've tried this for 2 days, no luck.

By the way, I'm not trying to use functions, just conditional statements, unless I have to? Then why not. Also, ignore the unnecessary use of headers, learning via tutorials at the moment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    int player[5] = {58, 66, 68, 71, 87};
    int goals[5] = {26, 39, 25, 29, 31};
    int gamesPlayed[5] = {30,30,28,30,26};
    float ppg[5];
    float bestPPG = 0.0;
    float worstPPG = 0.0;
    int bestPlayer;
    int worstPlayer;

    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {

        ppg[i] = (float)goals[i] / (float)gamesPlayed[i];
        printf("%d \t %d \t %d \t %.2f \n",player[i],goals[i], 
gamesPlayed[i],ppg[i]);

        if ( ppg[i] > bestPPG ) {

            if(bestPPG == 0.0)
            {
                worstPPG = ppg[i];
                worstPlayer = player[i];
            }

            if (ppg[i] < worstPPG)
            {

                worstPPG = ppg[i];
                worstPlayer = player[i];
            }

            bestPPG = ppg[i];
            bestPlayer = player[i];

        }

        if ( ppg[i] < bestPPG )
        {
            if ( ppg[i] < worstPPG ) {

                worstPPG = ppg[i];
                worstPlayer = ppg[i];
            }
        }

    }

    printf("\nThe best player is: %d \n", bestPlayer);
    printf("The worst player is: %d \n", worstPlayer);

    return 0;

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have this error:

```
worstPlayer = ppg[i];
```

where it should be:

```
worstPlayer = player[i];
```

Secondly, after fixing that, then even though your conditional statements are working they can be simplified a lot:

```
    if (i == 0) { // Initialize
        worstPPG = bestPPG = ppg[0];
        worstPlayer = bestPlayer = player[0];
    } else if ( ppg[i] > bestPPG ) {
        bestPPG = ppg[i];
        bestPlayer = player[i];
    } else if ( ppg[i] < worstPPG ) {
        worstPPG = ppg[i];
        worstPlayer = player[i];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Question: Do we have to initialize worst/bestPlayer at first? Obviously I see that we have to or else it won't work, but I don't understand why we can't leave it set to 0 if it will eventually change?

Comment: @n0de If you leave `worstPPG` set to `0.0` then it will **always** stay that way because `ppg[i]` will never be less than `0.0`. So you have to initialize it  and in my opinion, it's simplest to initialize it with the first value. If you do that, then you have to also initialize `worstPlayer` with the first player in case the first player is the worst one. And since you are already checking if the loop is at the first player, you might as well simplify by also initialize `bestPPG` and `bestPlayer`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to keep it simple : when you compute a new ppg either it is better than the bestPPG you have in memory (then you update the variable bestPPG with ppg) or it is lower than the worstPPG (then you update the variable worstPPG with ppg) or it is between (then you do nothing)

Beware of the initialisation of your variables : worstPPG is initialized to 0 but you'll never get a ppg under 0. Either you initialize it to plus infinity (see [this post](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm) for that), or you initilize it with the first value you compute.

In the loop, your code should look like that :

```
//compute ppg and display
if(ppg[i] < worstPPG){
    worstPPPG = ppg[i];
    worstPlayer = player[i];
}
else if(ppg[i] > bestPPG){
    bestPPG = ppg[i];
    besPlayer = player[i];
}
```